# Ошибка при установке/обновлении Veeam Backup & Replication 12 "VmWinError has been occurred. Error: 1312"

Tags: update, резервное-копирование, install, certificate

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
***Veeam***  Storage name: 'C:\ProgramData\Veeam\Setup\Temp{8A53D420-C57D-4D6F-97A6-C9A4FA9EBA35}\VmCertManage'.
***Veeam***  ========= VmCertManage: Executing.
***Veeam***  Execute commands (CertControl1):
***Veeam***    Command 'BIND_SERVICE'...
***Veeam***  Converting application guid '{c1c52494-c27c-427c-aa00-602f93215488}'...
***Veeam***  Converting port 9401...
***Veeam***  Getting thumbprint...
***Veeam***  Thumbprint is 'C8D38F5F91CCFF7469BE04DDEAF5F9612A571D65'...
***Veeam***  Binding certificate to port...
***Veeam***  VmWinError has been occurred. Error: 1312.
Error occurred during certificate processing.
CustomAction VmACertManage_Install returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 9:57:22: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.